# Scroll to bottom not working in an inactive tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, scroll

I'm trying to create a chrome extension content script that runs in inactive tab.

I have an infinite scroll element that I'd like to scroll to bottom.

If the tab is active and in foreground the following code works:

```
div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
```

If I'm in another tab, the scrolling doesn't work...

Is there a flag at `chrome://flag` that can fix it? Or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: I think you can create a new window in background (focused:false in chrome.windows.create) and move that tab to that window (chrome.tabs.move) to make it active in that window even though the window itself isn't active it should work IIRC.

Comment: I've tried this also, the behavior of windows is the same....
If the window is not in focus, the scrollHeight doesn't update :/

Comment: Can you upload full code (choose tab, choose element, ect) ?

Comment: This is the full code .. even if I open Instagram or facebook, opening the developer tool, moving to another tab and writing in console :
      
  div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;

the value of div.scrollTop stays the same as if   div.scrollTop never assigned :/

It seems like chrome freezes the UI changing if the tab is not visible.
Try it yourself and you'll see, if the tab is visible, it scrolls, otherwise, as said above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, After a long research, I finally have a conclusion.

When a tab is not visible (tab can be active but not visible), chrome doesn't do the UI calculations. 
Because of that, scrolling calculations are not done, only visible measurement can be done.

A workaround solution is to open the tab in new window, which make the tab visible (although this window is not focused)
and set "Throttle expensive background timers" in chrome://flags to disable

Comment: This is completely worthless workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with inactive tab 
and I was able to scroll it by generating a scroll event. See this code:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
evt.initEvent('scroll', false, true);
scrollTarget.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps others, I solved it by just waiting (polling) for the page to become visible:

```js
if(document.hidden) {
  while(document.hidden) await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  // do scrolling stuff here
}
```

But a much better solution for most people would use the `visibilitychanged` event of the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API):

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  if(document.hidden) {
    // tab has become inactive/hidden
  } else {
    // tab has become visible
  }
})
```

I haven't tested that code. You'll obviously need to add some extra code there to make sure it only triggers your `tab has become visible` code the first time that the page becomes visible (assuming that's what you want).

Comment: I tried this with the scroll function that I wrote and it stops when the tab is inactive.